# Imshow 2D array memory error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 2D array using imshow, however I get a memory error. I've tried to make it memory efficient by changing floats to ints where possible, but I still get the error.

The source file is a file with 3 columns: x, y and z (no header, space seperated). Since the X and Y are on a 5x5 grid I have divided by 5). The shape of the 2D array ("arr" in the example below) is (7422, 9637) which is large but I was not expexting it to be too large. Plotting only [:4000, :4000] is too much as well already.

The code I use:

```
fn = 'xyzData.pts'
data = pd.read_csv(fn, delim_whitespace=True, decimal='.', header=None, 
names=['x', 'y', 'z'], dtype={'x': np.int32, 'y': np.int32, 'z': np.float32})

minX = data.x.min()
maxX = data.x.max()
minY = data.y.min()
maxY = data.y.max()

stepSize = 5

arr = np.zeros(((int(maxY-minY)/stepSize)+1, (int(maxX-minX)/stepSize)+1))
arr[:,:] = np.nan
arr[((data.y-minY)/stepSize).astype(int), ((data.x-minX)/stepSize).astype(int)] = data.z

plt.imshow(arr, extent=(minX, maxX, maxY, minY), cmap=cm.gist_rainbow)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Is there anywhere where I need to improve my code or is imshow just flawed? In which case I need to find an alternative (any ideas?).

Help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can `imshow` handle `nan`-values? Does this code work with a really small matrix, say 10x10?

Comment: Yes, it does work with nan values. Nan values are represented as colorless pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Fixxed it using 64-bit python.